# Yet another dynamic_class failing with "invalid target type"

Tags: dynamic, casting

I am missing something ...

I have a class `SocketComm`. I have a derived class `SocketTCP : public SocketComm`.

`SocketComm` has the following in it:

```
static SocketComm *Instance; // static pointer to the singleton instance du jour
```

I am trying to define a method in `SocketComm` as follows:

```
static inline SocketTCP *GetTCPclass()
{
    // consistent method to return a SocketTCP* cast of SocketComm::Instance (or NULL)
    SocketTCP *s = dynamic_cast<SocketTCP *>(Instance);
    assert( s != NULL );
    return s;
}
```

I am getting (VS 2010)

> error C2680: 'SocketTCP *' : invalid target type for dynamic_cast

What am I missing? `SocketComm` is abstract -- is that the problem?

Comment: Can you post a minimal workable code that we can try to compile?

Comment: I now see more to the error message (in the Output panel, not the Error panel, which is why I missed it). "'SocketTCP' : class must be defined before using in a dynamic_cast." I tried adding a forward declaration class SocketTCP to SocketComm but that did not help. I am going to guess I am going to have to move GetTCPclass() from the header to the implementation, and make sure SocketTCP is defined (#include SocketTCP.h). Have not had a chance to try that yet.

Answer (score 1):

The answer seems to be that dynamic_cast needs a full declaration of the target class.

See my comment above.

Yeah, like @ViRusTriNiTy says, I suppose I could have put it in SocketTCP as a static inline. That would probably have worked too. But it seems more logical to me in the base class, and there is no performance reason to make it inline. The compiler will inline it when it can (in SocketComm.cpp) anyway.

Answer (score 0):

According to your comments you are mixing code that belongs to a derived class into a base class. This is the wrong approach and you now see why: `SocketTCP' : class must be defined before using in a dynamic_cast.`

Just approach this in a different way like say adding a separate helper class that does the dynamic_cast.

Comment: @Charles I edited my answer according to your comments.

Comment: Not really. I left it in SocketComm. I just got rid of the inline and did a "normal" implementation (in a .cpp with a #include "SocketTCP.h") and all is well.